# golang validator/v10 how to validate inner slice item required_if?

Tags: go, validation, go-gin

Here is my struct:

```
type StorePromotion struct {
    BatchStair   []*StairItem `json:"batch_stair" binding:"required,dive"`
    DiscountType string       `json:"discount_type" binding:"required,oneof=amount discount"`
}

type StairItem struct {
    SubjectNum int8  `json:"subject_num" binding:"required"`                    
    Value      int64 `json:"value" binding:"required"`                          
    Limit      int64 `json:"limit" binding:"required_if=DiscountType discount"` 
}
```

required tag validation works, but required_if does not.

my json:

```
 {
    "discount_type": "discount",
    "batch_stair": [{
            "subject_num": 2,
            "value": 100
        },
        {
            "subject_num": 2,
            "value": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

Expect verification to fail because discount_type=discount.
Is there a way to solve this without custom validation method?
I tested that reuqired_if which is not inside StairItem works ok.
[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/itL4b4Yl1RE)